# Configure Windows 2003 for psexec SMB exploit

Tags: windows, smb, metasploit

How do I configure windows 2003 to be ready to be exploited with SMB exploit? Basically I need to figure out how to turn the SMB service on and create users that would use it “normal.”

Here is the situation, I am demonstrating how vulnerable systems can be and why good security practices are important. I have 2 virtual machines on a NAT network in Virtual Box. One machine is a Windows 2003 server and the other is a Kali distro ready to exploit. The problem is I don’t know how to configure the Windows system to turn on the SMB service or whatever you have to do to get the exploit to work.

Answer (score 0):

SMB is turned on by default on all windows machines. The most likely cause what you are seeing as it being "off" is probably the Windows 2003 firewall is stopping your connections in. PSEXEC isn't an exploit, in Metasploit however it is in the "exploit" modules location 'exploit/windows/smb/psexec'. Try nmap against the Windows 2003 machine from the Kali box. If you get no ports open then the firewall is configured to block everything.